# Install MetaTrader5 using pip 22.3.1 and python 3.11.0 error

Tags: python, pip, metatrader5

I am trying to install MetaTrader5 on windows using pip.

```
python --version
Python 3.11.0

pip --version
pip 22.3.1

pip install MetaTrader5
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5
```

I have seen similar questions here but for Mac and Linux, And I'm on windows that's why I'm confused. Usually pip install MetaTrader5 alone was all I needed to make it work.

But this time I get this error. Might it be because of the PIP or Python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current latest version MetaTrader5 5.0.43 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/5.0.43/#files) for Python 3.6-3.10. Not for 3.11 and no source code.

Downgrade your Python to 3.10. Make sure to install 64-bit version.