# Cannot install MT5 python on Mac M1

Tags: python, metatrader5

When try to install MT5 on Mac M1 getting below Error. I pretty much tried with different version of both MT5 and Python interpreter. Has anyone installed this on MAC/M1 if so please share the steps.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346030/install-metatrader5-using-pip-22-3-1-and-python-3-11-0-error