Python packaged installed on Windows11, but not found when call
I am using OSX 14.4.1 (23E224). Running parallel 18 + Windows 11.
I have to run Windows because MetaTrader5(MT5) python package is not support OSX.
Use 3.10 because it does support up to 3.10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/74346406/1019455
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Mac\Home\Documents> python -V
Python 3.10.11

I installed pip-tools in order to use pip-compile
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Mac\Home\Documents> pip freeze                                              build==1.2.1                                                                                                           click==8.1.7                                                                                                           colorama==0.4.6                                                                                                        packaging==24.0
pip-tools==7.4.1
pyproject_hooks==1.1.0
tomli==2.0.1


Problem:
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Mac\Home\Documents> pip-compile
pip-compile : The term 'pip-compile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip-compile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip-compile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Mac\Home\Documents> pip -V
pip 24.0 from C:\Users\sarit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

Attempt:
I have search the Internet, I found not related to my question for example
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/adding-python-path-to-windows-10-or-11-path-environment-variable/
I don't found Python like this article.
    Directory: C:\Users\sarit\AppData\Local


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         4/29/2024  12:32 AM                Comms
d-----         4/29/2024  12:31 AM                ConnectedDevicesPlatform
d-----         4/29/2024  12:39 AM                Microsoft
d-----          5/5/2024  12:55 PM                Packages
d-----          5/5/2024  12:34 PM                PlaceholderTileLogoFolder
d-----         4/29/2024  12:40 AM                Publishers
d-----          5/7/2024  10:39 AM                Temp
d-----         4/29/2024  12:32 AM                VirtualStore
-a----          5/7/2024  10:24 AM           1855 parallels.log
-a----          5/5/2024  12:56 PM          14932 prlextscache.ini


PS C:\Users\sarit\AppData\Local>


The current latest version MetaTrader5 5.0.4288 provides wheels for Python 3.6-3.12.

Uninstall 3.10 version by clicking on the icon and right click to uninstall.
I did try looking at control panel, but it shows only python launcher.
After I uninstall and install pip-tools again. I carefully read this message and found the missing variable in my PATH.
 WARNING: The script wheel.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\sarit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script pyproject-build.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\sarit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pip-compile.exe and pip-sync.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\sarit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Add them to PATH solve the problem.
